# Minimal Cover of Functional Dependencies

Tags: sql, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, cover

Question:[image]

```
The answer I keep on coming with is: 
A => BE
C => D
BD => F
EF => B
BE => AC
```

But ideally the answer should be:

[image]

Can someone please explain if I am correct [There can be multiple minimal covers] and if I am not where have gone wrong?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Answer (score 1):

Let me make it simple:

Follow these rules to find minimal cover

> -Singleton Right hand side attributes
>
> -Check for extraneous attributes on left hand side and remove it
>
> -Remove the redundant covers

And,let me come to your answer:

> A->BE
>
> C->D
>
> BD->F
>
> EF->B
>
> BE->AC

Apply Armstrong's axiom to these relations:

By transivity rule,we get

> A->BE and BE->AC as A->AC

Then,by decomposition rule,we get

> **A->C** from A->AC

Then,by Union rule,we get

> A->BCE
> Then,by decomposition rule,we get
> BE->AC as BE->A and BE->C

But,

> we can get,
>
> BE->C from A->BE and A->C
>
> Thus,BE->C can be removed

**Final Anwer**

> A->BCE
>
> C->D
>
> BD->F
>
> EF->B
>
> BE->A

Thus,Your Answer is **Correct**.

Hope,it helps!